# python: create a new 1D list with values from 2 different lists:

Tags: python

Below is a simple example.  What I want is to create a new list that contain the values [0,1,2,3,4] by merging list1 and list 2 together. But the code below doesn't work and I am not really sure how I should solve it.

```
list1 = [3]
list2 = [i for i in range(3)]
newlist = list1.append(list2)
```

Comment: The correct answer is to use extend but there are tons of questions here that answer that so I'd recommend a little further research cause people will tend to down vote something like this. Good luck in the future

Comment: `list1 + list2`

Comment: @mikescotty not sure which is a better dupe cause he is currently using append

Comment: @fordprefect explaining why append does not achieve what OP wants would be a better reference.

Comment: @ThatUmbrellaGuy Good point... now where is someone with a dupehammer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.append(b)` doesn't return a new list containing the elements of `list` and `b`, but it will extend `list` by one element (the element `b`) and save the result in `list` itself.

To concatenate two lists, simply use the + operator. Your code would look like this:

```
list1 = [3] 
list2 = [i for i in range(3)]
newlist = list1 + list2
```

Comment: Hi this question is very much a duplicate. If you come across duplicate questions please flag them and mark them as duplicates. Answering them encourages further bad behavior

Answer (score 0):

**@MathiasRa**, your code will not work as **append()** 
method doesn't return any list.

Previous answers are appreciated. So can directly get your merged list `[0, 1, 2, 3]` using the below line.

```
list1 = [3]
list2 = [i for i in range(3)]
newlist = sorted(list1 + list2)

print (newlist) # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

#### » If you don't want updated list as return value

Use **extend()** method in place of **append()** as follows:

> **Note:** In this case, you won't get anything returned like **append()**. The statement will update the **calling list** (list1) by appending all items of **passing list** (list2).

```
list1 = [3]
list2 = [i for i in range(3)]
list1.extend(list2)

print(list1) # [3, 0, 1, 2]
print(sorted(list1)) # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Hi this question is very much a duplicate. If you come across duplicate questions please flag them and mark them as duplicates. Answering them encourages further bad behavior.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will.